# How do I change the default text editor in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-editors

How can I change the default text editor for console programs in Ubuntu.
When I run mutt and send a message, it currently loads up Joe and I would prefet to load Vim.
I know I can change $EDITOR for me only, but would prefe to do it system wide.

Comment: This is certainly one of the dumbest things ubuntu has done, setting Emacs (or Joe whatever) as the default editor.
And to make matters worse no regular vim, just tiny or basic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change $EDITOR systemwide. Just drop a short script into `/etc/profile.d/` which does this. The file only needs a single line:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/myeditor
```

*Edit:*

There are two ways (at least :-/) in which a program can find an editor to launch. The traditional Unix/Linux mechanism is to use $EDITOR. In addition to that, Debian (and therefore Ubuntu) has special aliases for various kinds of programs. These are provided by the "alternatives" system (a system of configurable symlinks). For editors this provides the aliases `editor` and `sensible-editor`. These can be updated using update-alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

(same for sensible-editor). This will prompt you for the editor to use.

However, in Debian programs are suppposed to read $EDITOR first:

> Thus, every program that launches an
>   editor or pager must use the EDITOR or
>   PAGER environment variable to
>   determine the editor or pager the user
>   wishes to use. If these variables are
>   not set, the programs /usr/bin/editor
>   and /usr/bin/pager should be used,
>   respectively.
>
> These two files are managed through the dpkg "alternatives" mechanism.

[...]

> If it is very hard to adapt a program
>   to make use of the EDITOR or PAGER
>   variables, that program may be
>   configured to use
>   /usr/bin/sensible-editor and
>   /usr/bin/sensible-pager as the editor
>   or pager program respectively.

(Debian Policy Manual, http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s11.4 )

In one sentence:  Setting $EDITOR globally should be enough.

Comment: Thanks - I had heard of the "alternatives" mechanism but counldnt remember enough to find it. It is really complicated though.

Comment: Actually `visudo` will not typically work with `$EDITOR` as it is a security concern (at least for ubuntu). The `/usr/bin/editor` is used.

Comment: `visudo` now uses `$EDITOR` in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

the mechanism in ubuntu (debian) used to solve this problem is described in `man update-alternatives`. essentially it provides a "pseudo binary" (`/usr/bin/editor`) which points to the right binary (the "best" alternative)

call

```
% sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

to change the current "default". with

```
% update-alternatives --list editor
% update-alternatives --display editor
```

you can see the currently available alternatives.

Comment: This is correct, but editor/sensible-editor is only meant as a fallback mechanism. You can just set $EDITOR. Also, editor/sensible-editor is a Debian convention. Third-party software may not use it, while $EDITOR is a general Unix tradition.

Comment: correct (i am aware of that). it is just a bit tricky to enforce EDITOR to all kind of shells (tcsh, zsh) anyway ... so changing /usr/bin/editor to the wanted default is enough, imho. as a "user" i set my own EDITOR anyway.